# Ubuntu Symantec compatibility

Tags: compatibility

A software vendor has told me that Ubuntu Server 12.04 is not compatible with Symantec's Endpoint Protection Version 12 Anti-Virus software.  Was I told correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article:
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH101598.html

They support Ubuntu 12.04

Also here:

http://www.symantec.com/endpoint-protection/system-requirements/ 
...they mention symantec endpoint protection 12.1.6, and Ubuntu is listed in supported OS (but version is not specified)

**@mark kirby**: There is even a tutorial on their website, says it works for Ubuntu

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-install-symantec-endpoint-protection-1215-ru5-linux-operating-system

Also as **@JoKeR** pointed out, there is site with supported kernels:

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH223240.html

Comment: you also can include [this link](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH223240.html) despite of distro version it shows supported kernels list.